# XML Schema validation issues

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write an XML schema for these lines:

```
<place id = "1234">
   <placeName lang = "de" type = "std"> SOMENAME <gender> n </gender> </placeName>
</place>
```

The schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
<xs:element name="place">
    <xs:complexType >
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType"> 

           <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name= "placeName">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">

                        <xs:sequence>  
                         <xs:element name= "gender" type= "xs:string"/>

                        </xs:sequence>    
                        <xs:attribute name= "lang" type= "xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name= "type" type= "xs:string" />             
                    </xs:extension>

                 </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType> 
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
       </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>   
   </xs:schema>
```

I continue to receive this error: E [Xerces] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_placeNameplace' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
"sequence" indicated is the 2nd one, for "gender"-tag.

---

After I made some changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
<xs:element name="place">
    <xs:complexType >
     <xs:complexContent mixed = "true">
       <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"> 

           <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name= "placeName">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:complexContent mixed= "true">
                     <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">

                        <xs:sequence>  
                         <xs:element name= "gender" type= "xs:string"/>

                        </xs:sequence>    
                        <xs:attribute name= "lang" type= "xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name= "type" type= "xs:string" />             
                    </xs:extension>

                 </xs:complexContent>
               </xs:complexType> 
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>   
</xs:schema>
```

I continue to receive this error: cos-nonambig: placeName and WC[##any] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles

Comment: The question is closed, thank you everybody! I found this magical tool: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html My problem was that I could not specify "string" (SOMENAME) if the node (placeName) already contained attributes-strings and a submode-string. But according to the xml-xsd convertor above I don't even need to specify that a node contains a text-string. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `sequence` inside `simpleContent`, I suspect what you really want is to use `complexContent` but make the type `mixed="true"`.

Comment: thank you! I changed it as you said, and added "mixed" to places' node. I edited the question. Now I have another error, but in overall in looks better - now all of my nodes and attributes are present when I visualise the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Extending xs:anyType doesn't work. It's saying "you can have any sequence of elements, followed by a placename". That's intrinsically unparseable without lookahead, because when you find a placename you don't know whether it's part of the "any sequence of elements", or the final placename.

By the way, please don't edit your question in this way to turn it into a completely different question. It makes it impossible to make sense of existing answers.

Comment: If I put "xs:string" instead of anyType, I still get errors, this time another one: [Xerces] src-ct.1: Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type '#AnonType_place'. When   is used, the base type must be a complexType. 'string' is a simpleType.

Comment: question is reedited, now it includes the initial version of the code

Comment: It's not at all clear why you want to define your type by restriction or extension from something else. Why not just define it "ab initio"?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get what you mean by ab initio? What exactly should I change in my code?

Comment: Sorry for the Latin. I meant, define a type that just defines the elements and attributes it is allowed to contain, without trying to derive it by restriction or extension from a different type.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I actually deleted all these restrictions and extensions, but it still didn't work correctly. I am very new to XML-schema, so I finally found this online-tool freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html, it is really what I need at the moment...